# What does "sharing the same CLR" mean specifically/concrete?

Tags: serialization, akka.net

In [documentation of Akka.Net](http://getakka.net/articles/networking/serialization.html) I read the following:

> Normally, messages sent between local actors (i.e. same CLR) do not
>   undergo serialization.

"Local actors that share the same CLR", what does that mean?
Are they on the same physical/virtual machine, in the same process, on the same thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that by default messages send between actors working in the same process/app domain are not serialized. For this reason (and as good practice in general) it's important to keep message data immutable.

Comment: It is a good observation that for this reason immutability is esp. important.

Comment: "same process/app domain" are you absolutely sure? Because they are two different words with two different meanings so why a slash in between? Which one is correct?

Comment: Since app domains cannot share objects, there is no way to pass messages without serializing them (in this context more popular word is marshaling). But in most cases we don't work in multi app-domain environment, so the natural unit of containment here is simply a process.